# Web scraping using python for multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a beautifulsoup parser to get all content of html. How do i scrape the web  when it hs multiple pages. like,
myurl  = "https://www.mybanktracker.com/ABC-Bank/Reviews"
the url has 20 off pages like
https://www.mybanktracker.com/ABC-Bank/Reviews/pages/1
https://www.mybanktracker.com/ABC-Bank/Reviews/pages/2 and so on.
How do i extract all the pages infro into one? or any other easier way to do so?

Comment: Use the same parsing logic for the first page and just use a for loop for the desired amount of pages? Do you even have one page functioning? What are you trying to extract from each page?

Comment: When you use the URL to scrape, just do something like: `for x in range(NUMBER OF PAGES HERE): scrapemethod('base_url...page/' + str(x))`. Obviously with Python, make sure your indentation is correct. I didn't want to post an answer because this has already been discussed on SO. But hopefully you'll understand from the comment I left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been examining the series of pages that begin with https://www.mybanktracker.com/TD-Bank/Reviews. The formatting of the top of first page appears to differ somewhat from that of the second and subsequent pages. I will therefore assume that you are arranging to parse all of the pages in such a way as to capture information below the heading 'Latest  Reviews'.

I suggest that you process pages in a `while` loop. It's likely that the number of pages of reviews differs from one bank to another. Rather than trying to recover the number of pages you could just keep requesting pages until you get an empty page. (I've found that a request for 'page 52' in this series yields a page with no reviews.) Here is some pseudo-code.

```
URL = https://www.mybanktracker.com/TD-Bank/Reviews
pageNumber = 1
while True:
    fetch, parse and store information from one page
    if no reviews found in page then break
    pageNumber += 1
    URL = https://www.mybanktracker.com/TD-Bank/Reviews/page/pageNumber
```

Comment: Yes, that logic does apply but as you can tell he doesn't have the knowledge of basic for loops. It would be probably better to refer him to python basics and bs4 basics before giving him the logic behind it.

Comment: @FaultyFuse: Well the OP is welcome to seek further advice from me.